# Adding multiple instant vectors together

Tags: prometheus

I am trying to add a group of gauges to a vector() while still keeping their time series data in Prometheus.

**For example:** 1 day worth of data

`Vector(10) = 10.0` all day

`Gauge1 = 0.1 (0100 - 1800, else = no data)`

`Gauge2 = 0.2 (0200 - 1900, else = no data)`

`Gauge3 = 0.3 (0300 - 2000, else = no data)`

`Gauge4 = 0.4 (0400 - 2100, else = no data)`

**My goal is to get the values:**

```
10.0 (0000 - 0100)

10.1 (0100 - 0200)

10.3 (0200 - 0300)

10.6 (0300 - 0400)

11.0 (0400 - 1800)

10.9 (1800 - 1900)

10.7 (1900 - 2000)

10.4 (2000 - 2100)

10.0 (2100 - 0000)
```

I have tried working with `or`, `and`, and `unless`, however, it gets very complicated the more gauges you have. I am also using `ignoring` so that the gauges are able to be summed together.

Is there an easy way I can accomplish this? All I want to do is add the gauge to the static vector if there is data.

Edit:

For more detail on my specific case. I have gauges that show values in `seconds` (since a job finished). I filter for where the values are less than `300` (since the jobs are updated every `5 minutes`). I then take the `hour() + min() - secondsSinceEnd()` to get the `hour` and `minute` the job ended. I take the `minimum_over_time()` for the whole day since it runs once per day. This results in a new value starting at the time the job finished. I compare this result to the expected end time to get the difference.

I want to add all these differences up and combine them with the expected end time of all the jobs.

Example:

`vector(12) + min_over_time((hour(timestamp(0 < JobSecondsSinceEnd{} < 300)) + round((minute(timestamp(0 < JobSecondsSinceEnd{} < 300)) - (0 < JobSecondsSinceEnd{} < 300)/60))/60)[24h:15s])`

Comment: It's unclear what math you're actually asking for here, I'm not seeing the link between the input and the output.

Comment: I've edited my post with more detail. Hopefully it makes more since now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my case, I found a work around. I still feel like there could be an easier way, but this is what I came up with.

For each instant vector that I want to sum, I added a `vector(0)` to it.

```
vector(10) + (vector(A) OR vector(0)) + 
(vector(B) OR vector(0)) + ...
```